# How could we serialize selectpicker plugin text on different tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, tabs, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have got the problem when i am trying to use two `selectpicker` but in different tab like the code below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
         style: 'btn-default'
     });
})

$('#test').click(function(){
    var test = $('#okay').serialize();
    alert(test);
    console.log(test);
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <form id="okay">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="1">
        
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="okse" id="okse">
          <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
             <option value="2012">2012</option>
        </select>
        <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="4">
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="6">
      <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="7">
      <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="8">
      <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="okse1" id="okse1">
        <option value="Matt">matt</option>
         <option value="Dessy">Dess</option>
        </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>
<br>

<button id="test">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The result i got is

```
1=&okse=2010&4=&6=&7=&8=
```

the id `okse1` didnt include in jquery serialized. WHat i expect was like below:

```
1=&okse=2010&4=&6=&7=&8=&okse1=matt
```

or i  got an empty result but the id `okse1` got serialized

```
1=&okse=2010&4=&6=&7=&8=&okse1=
```

As you could see above snippet, the `selectpicker` with id `okse1` didnt serialized when i clicked `button#test`. if the selectpicker was in different tab, it didint serialized. How do i fix this ?

Comment: form is closed before second tab's div. Cant this be a problem?

Comment: @entio my closed form is in second tabs, so there is no problem

Comment: @entio i mean the other input text in second tab was serialized, but the select picker in the second tab didnt

Comment: 1/ `input` is self-closing tag. `select` contains `options`. Serlializing select is another story. 2/ never expext code to work right way if your markdown is broken, just tip from my experience. See answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your HTML markup as in suggestion. Form is closed before second tab's div. Opened in the first one. Here's fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkxewpbn/

```
<form id="okay">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">

    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="1">

    <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="okse" id="okse">
         <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
         <option value="2012">2012</option>
    </select>
    <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="4">
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="6">
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="7">
  <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="8">
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="okse1" id="okse1">
       <option value="Matt">matt</option>
     <option value="Dessy">Dess</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: my appologize i could find the different your code and with my code, but your code seems working.. what tag did you changed ?

Comment: can you mention that in your answer, which section did you changed  ?

Comment: @gagantous quoting my answer `Form is closed before second tab's div. Opened in the first one.`

Comment: as i wrote in the comment below answer - markup was broken.

Comment: always. everywhere.

Comment: why the div got broken ? it's like the content going down or pushed down

Comment: how do i fixed that ?

Comment: You had this:

    <div class="1">
       <form>
    </div>
    <div class="2">
       </form>
    </div>

you have to do this:

    <form>
        <div class="1"></div>
        <div class="2"></div>
     </form>